# Assistance with Excel Formatting/Formula/Equations

Tags: excel

I have been building an automated trading robot. I have done this via using a virtual GUI in order to integrate it.

I want to be able to analyze the data using Excel. The problem is that I don't know how to organize the data on excel to give me the most vital information. So I thought there wouldn't be a better place to post this then stackoverflow. I have been looking for the "right" youtube video, which would be able to describe what I am looking for.

1.) Count for maximum loss trade sequence( I.e. If the program loss three times in the row as the max, this would be the count for it.)

2.)Count for maximum win trade sequence ( Same thing as mentioned previously, but for wins)

3.) Count for "Pages" loss trade sequence (Every 10 trades equals 1 page. This would mean that if we have 6 losses out of the 10 trades this consists of 1 loss page, if next ten trades consist the same thing or more losses then this means we have 2 pages of loss trade sequence.)

4.) Count for "Pages" Win trade sequence (Every 10 trades equals 1 page. This would mean the same as "Count for Pages loss trade sequence" just for wins instead.)

5.) Count for "Pages" Draw trade sequence ( Every 10 trades equals 1 page. This would mean we had 5 winning and losing trades out of the 10)

6.) Maximum Win pages in a row ( How many pages we won in a row based on #4 calculation)

7.) Maximum Lost pages in a row ( How many pages we lost in a row based on #3 calculation)

8.) Average of winning trades # (Averaging total amount of wins in a row)

9.) Average of losing trades # (Averaging total amount of losses in a row)

Examples below are correlated numerically with list above.

1. H:27-H:22 is the maximum lost trade sequence = 6
2. H:1-H:5 is the maximum win sequence = 5
3. (Rounding) is the total of losing pages = 2 (locations H:39-H:30 and H:29-H:20)
4. (Rounding) is the total of winning pages =  2 (locations H:50- H:41 and H-10:H-1)
5. (Ronding) is the total of drawn pages = 1 (location H:60-H:69)
6. There were no wins in a row
7. Two page losses in a row (H:39-H:20)
8. (would take count of wins / sequential wins count) i.e. if we had 10 sequences of winning in a row out of 100 wins this would equal 1 every ten times as the average
9. (would take count of losses / sequential losses) ^^ same thing except for losses

Any help would be greatly appreciated, heck even a youtube video. I have been working on this program for a while. I learned the hard way, and noticed that I need better data management. Thanks in advance!

"[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61fuZ.png)"

Comment: Have you considered functions like: averageif(), sumif() countif() maxifs() minifs() etc?

Comment: I have , but I dont know how to apply it in the way stated above.. If for example I want the result of each sequence in its own seperate way that would help.